# How can I programatically create an in/out system?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, webforms

Basically, I want to design a table which has a check-in/check-out functionality, where the user presses a button and is checked in or out, depending on their previous status. I have created the webform.aspx in Visual Studios.

```
    <title> Check-in Board </title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="logo.png" class="center" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%--<asp:Panel ID="toggleSwitch" runat="server">--%>
        <table id="board">
            <tr>
                <th> In </th>
                <th> Out </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <td>
                    firstName lastName <button type="button" class="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()"> Out </button>
                </td>

                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                        var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
                        //x.disabled = true;
                        alert("You have signed out.");
                        //remove cell with person name under in column
                        $("#board").on('click', '.myBtn', function () {
                            $(this).closest('td').remove();
                            //create new cell
                            var row = document.getElementById("row");
                            var x = row.insertCell(-1);
                            x.innerHTML = "firstName lastName";
                            //create new button in new cell
                            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                            btn.innerHTML = "In";
                            document.body.appendChild(btn);
                            //click button to move to In column
                            btn.onclick = function () {
                                alert("You have signed in.");
                                var row = document.getElementById("row");

                                var y = row.insertCell(0);
                                var z = row.deleteCell(-1);
                                y.innerHTML = "firstName lastName";

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    </script>
                <td>

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    </td>

                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%--</asp:Panel>--%>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If the person is "in", then the "in" column would display their name and a button that says "out", that, once pressed, would move them over to the "out" column, with a new button that says "in", and vice versa. I think i am getting the first part right, the name is displaying in the "in" column with an "out" button, and when clicked, switches them over to the out column. The problem arises when I try to press the "in" button in the "out column" (to check them in); it brings them back to the "in" column, but with no button. What do I need to do to fix this? Do I need to have a loop?

Comment: I would just make a list of the names in both the left and right column. Hide one by default and then toggle the visibility of the two depending on the "in" or "out" state that they're in.

Comment: That sounds so much easier... can't believe i didn't think of that. Thank you, I will give it a shot and get back.